# Sending Vuex State To Backend

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to send a state in Vuex that is an array of objects to my backend. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property '$options' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'router' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'app' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at transformRequest (defaults.js?6d1b:52)
    at transform (transformData.js?e0e9:16)
    at Object.forEach (utils.js?a2f8:232)
    at transformData (transformData.js?e0e9:15)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js?82e5:30)
```

I am using axios to post to my backend, and here is my axios post method call:

```js
SET_ITEMS: (state) => {
    const items = state.items;
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/boards/update-list', { list: items });
}
```

I have tried multiple things one being the uses flatted package ([Flatted](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted)), however, to no avail. How can I fix this error? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
In my case, I have manually given value to the state.items.

```
state: {
        items: [
            {
                x: 100,
                y: 200,
            },
            {
                x: 50,
                y: 400,
            },
            {
                x: 100,
                y: 100,
            },
            {
                x: 350,
                y: 300,
            }
        ]
    }
```

**SECOND EDIT**
Moved async call into a action:

```
setItems: ({state}) => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/boards/update-list', { hey: state.items})
}
```

Comment: @Phil I console.log state.items and I got {__ob__: Observer}. I will also move the async call to an action instead of mutation.

Comment: @Phil I made a edit to my post. state.items is set manually.

Comment: @Phil Yes, I have no mutation changing state.items. Yes, I have moved the async call into action. I did some testing and saw that changing `{ list: items }` to `{ list: [ {} ] }` (which seems to be no different from `state.items`), doesn't throw the error. Also, logging `state.items` gives `[__ob__: Observer]` and logging `[{}]` gives `[{...}]`. I don't know what to update my question to.

Comment: @Phil I've edited the post to show what I currently have in the action.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem ~ https://jsfiddle.net/Lsbkd6qh/2/. There must be something else you're not showing. Are you doing anything with the Axios response? The error message looks to me like you're actually trying to stringify a Vue instance / component and not the array from your store. I suspect somewhere you're overwriting the `store.items` with something else

Comment: @Phil I think I figured out where the error is coming from. For the state items, I didn't include one more value which is `element: [HTMLElement]`. I set this value in one of my components. When I remove the setting of this value, the error no longer happens.

Comment: @Phil Yup the problem is exactly the  `element: [HTMLElement]`. Because of this value, I get the circular structure to JSON.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't mention this in the question, but I have a value in `state.items` where the element (HTMLElement) is being stored. This has been causing the error mentioned in the question. How I solved this was by completing leaving out the `element` value from `JSON.stringify`. You can accomplish this by creating a replacer function and here is mine in my case:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
    if (key === 'element') return undefined;
    return value;
}
```

Then you can put this function in the JSON.stringify as shown here:

```
JSON.stringify(state.items, replacer(key, value))
```

And now the `element` value is not included after the `JSON.stringify` method call!

I hope someone finds this helpful.